# Jquery mobile automatically converting my nested unordered lists to links? What should i do

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying something like this in my jquery mobile project -

I am asking a user to input html and css in two textboxes, and then retrieving those values using jquery and then appending the styles and the html in the div -

```
<div id="resultContainer">

</div>
```

Now, all others go fine but when i input the codes -

```
<ul id="genus_examples">
    <li>Cats
        <ul>
            <li>Panthera</li>
            <li>Felis</li>
            <li>Neofelis</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Apes
        <ul>
            <li>Pongo</li>
            <li>Pan</li>
            <li>Homo</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But Jquery mobile automatically converts my code to something like this -

```
<ul id="genus_examples">
    <li><a href="#demo-page&amp;ui-page=2-1" class="ui-link"><span>Cats</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#demo-page&amp;ui-page=2-0" class="ui-link"><span>Apes</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

So, jquery is converting my unordered list to something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/9TKM4/1/

When you click to open the sidebar and then select the option child selector to generate code provided in helperTextHtml jquery changes the text to something else and thats why i think such erroneous result i am getting, please help

Comment: Add `data-role=none` attribute  to ul.

Comment: No dude, it aint working I tried it in fiddle now
http://jsfiddle.net/9TKM4/2/

Comment: Your code is inside `<ul class="left-nav" data-icon="" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-divider-theme="b">` which enhances all children. `.helperTextHtml` code is being converted to a _Nested listview - jQM widget_ so you fetch it enhanced from DOM. Instead, use variable to store the code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9TKM4/4/ and here is the difference between normal list and nested listview http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SS2g9/